# Calling a method when a Class name is used like a method

Tags: ruby, class, methods, callback

I'm wondering if one could define a class in Ruby to have the following sort of usage:

```
Class Book
    def Book
        puts self.to_s 
    end
    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
    end
    def to_s
        @name.to_s
    end
end
```

Usage:

```
Book "To Kill a Mocking Bird"   #=>To Kill a Mocking Bird
```

The idea that I want is for this to behave like the following

1. An instance of the method is created (as a short hand).
2. The method Book is immediately called after this and performs a block of code.

(The intent of having the method named the same as the class is to have the call back when it is used like a method.)

Is this possible in Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
class Book
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    self.name = name
  end

  def to_s
    name
  end
end

def Book(name)
  Book.new(name)
end

puts Book("To Kill a Mocking Bird")
```

---

As a minor point of interest, [Ruby's `Kernel` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html) uses such a technique (written in C) to implement methods named `Array`, `String`, and so on:

```
Array(12)          #=> [12]
String(12)         #=> '12'
Integer('0x12')    #=> 18
```

Comment: @JimPedid, don't forget to upvote/accept good answers. You can read about accepting answers in [this brief FAQ article](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
class Book
    def show_me
        puts self.to_s 
    end
    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
        show_me
    end
    def to_s
        @name.to_s
    end
end
```

show_me will be executed but once you create a new book, the book object will be returned at the end.

```
>> Book.new "To Kill a Mocking Bird"
To Kill a Mocking Bird
=> #<Book:0x74f63f0 @name="To Kill a Mocking Bird">
```